# How to add a background image to a Gmail message

Tags: gmail, gmail-themes

I want to have a background image while I compose a new message in Gmail. I must be able to type over it. Is it possible?

Comment: Was that 'while you compose a message' or 'adding it to the message' you send?

Comment: While composing.

Comment: This is probably counter-productive but I can't resist: Please, please please please please please for the sake of everyone's sanity do not add a background image to your emails. You may think it looks pretty but you are **not** the one reading your emails. :)

Comment: If you just want an image while composing (and not to send) you can use something like stylish.

Answer (score 3):

This may fly in the face of how you want to do it but, you can set up your Gmail account as a regular email (have to enable POP/IMAP in gmail.com prefs first) Once you've done that .. I use Mozilla's SeaMonkey (think Firefox with an email client) and when composing my message
go to Tools, format page colors and background
then select your background image
pick colors that will show up clearly over it
and click ok.

For me, this is the easiest way to put a background in my messages.
I only use a background once in a blue moon but, when you want to, well .. go for it.
(sorry it's not an answer that will work in the web)